# In an array like a[0-15] how do I check if any arrays are the same, and merge their totals if they are?

Tags: c

So I have an array:

```
accounts[MAX]
```

And it's a parallel array with an amount[MAX] and debitorcredit[MAX] array, the debitorcredit array holds if its a 'c' or 'd' value and amount holds the $$ amount. How do I search if accounts[3] has the same account number as accounts[5] (or any combination of numbers) and if they are the same, to add the amount value and combine the arrays? So if

```
accounts[3] = 1500 and accounts[5] = 1500
```

have the value of

```
amount[3] = 100, amount[5] = 130
```

and

```
debitorcredit[3] = 'c'   , debitorcredit[5] = 'd'
```

it would combine the account # of 1500 into 1 array with the amount value of 30 (130 - 100)?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk: Please stop using the homework tag.  It is OBSOLETE, as per the tag description.  :)

Answer (score 2):

To test all pairs of account numbers to see which are equal, use

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    for (j = i; j < MAX; j++) { // note: starts from i, not 0
        if(accounts[i] == accounts[j]) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

However, you can't merge the two account numbers into one array element and just delete the other array element, since you've already defined `accounts` to have the fixed size `MAX` and arrays allocated in this way cannot be dynamically reallocated.  In your example, you may wish to set the 5th index of all the arrays to some dummy value, like -1.  Then, when you read from the array, you can pass over all elements with this dummy value.

Comment: yes the     if (accounts[3] == accounts[5]) would work but how would I loop that to test all account combinations? since I can't do accounts[i] == accounts[i+1] because that would only compare one variable with the one next to it and not all of them

Comment: If it works for you, don't forget that you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. </shameless rep plug>

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing, I think, is to sort the arrays by account number.  This would be best achieved by rearranging your data into structures and then using `qsort`.

```
struct account_entry {
    int account_num;
    int amount;        // assuming int
    char debit_credit;
};
```

Then you would have a single array:

```
struct account_entry acc[MAX];
for( i = 0; i < MAX; i++ ) {
    acc[i].account_num = accounts[i];
    acc[i].amount = amount[i];
    acc[i].debit_credit = debit_or_credit[i];
}
```

And sort it:

```
int compare_entry( const void* a, const void* b )
{
    const struct account_entry *aa = (const account_entry*)a;
    const struct account_entry *bb = (const account_entry*)b;
    if( aa->account_num < bb->account_num ) return -1;
    if( aa->account_num > bb->account_num ) return 1;
    return 0;  // No need to do second-tier sorting if accounts are equal.
}

qsort( acc, MAX, sizeof(struct account_entry), compare_entry );
```

Now you just run through the array and consolidate.  Easiest to consolidate into a new array.

```
struct account_entry consolidated[MAX];
int c = 0, i;
consolidated[0] = acc[0];

for( i = 1; i < MAX; i++ ) {
    if( acc[i].account_num != consolidated[c].account_num ) {
        c++;
        consolidated[c] = acc[i];
    } else {
        // Add the amounts and work out whether it's debit or credit...  Do
        // not increment c.  Dunno why you don't drop this field altogether
        // and allow negative values, but nevermind.  As such, I won't put
        // code for it in here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely. I don't know where I 'read' that they were account names. Anyways, it's probably because the OP didn't show code :)

Comment: Thats probably the proper and most effcient way to do it but im in an entry level programming course and that is too advanced for me plus my prof wouldn't accept it!

Comment: Well, you could do the naive O(N^2) thing in that case...  It'll be what everyone else is doing.  I dunno...  When I was in entry-level programming at uni, I'd already been programming for several years.  My lecturers never had a problem with it - maybe because there was no stackoverflow and they knew the answers were actually mine =)  Maybe you should've stated that you were expected not to use structures or sorting...

Comment: @Paddy I feel the same way. I think your answer nails it. Mine should help the OP understand what goes on underneith. There's nothing more we can do. +1 for the comment as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple iteration in two arrays, comparing every value:

```
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < MAX; ++j)
    {
         if (array_one[i] == array_two[j])
         {
              // do stuff ...
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ouch. This is not working well with name comparisons... Also, doesn't check the 'valid' indices. Last but not least it has O(n^2) runtime, and that's only for 2 arrays

Comment: ... ? valid indicies = ? My english is not that good, but as I understood the OP can't iterate trough a simple array and you comment on complexity? And who is talking about name comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read up on structs:

```
typedef struct record
{
    const char* name;
    double amount;    /* fixed point, 3 decimals? */
    char deb_cred;    /* 'd' or 'c' (prefer to use `signed char` for a direct sign? */
} record_t;
```

So instead of

```
#define MAX 15

const char* accounts [MAX] = { "John Mayor", "Paula Bean", "Gary S.", "John Mayor" }; 
double amount        [MAX] = { 100.00      , 200.00      , 300.00   , 400.00       }; 
char debitorcredit   [MAX] = { 'd'         , 'd'         , 'c'      , 'c'          };
```

Where simple functions would get implemented rather complex:

```
double get_balance_arrays(const char* name)
{
    double total = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<MAX && accounts[i]; ++i)
    {
        if(0 == strcmp(accounts[i], name))
            switch(debitorcredit[i])
            {
                case 'c': total += amount[i]; break;
                case 'd': total -= amount[i]; break;
                default:
                    puts("Invalid transaction");
                    exit(255);
            }
    }
    return total;
}
```

You'd write

```
record_t transactions[MAX] =
{
    { "John Mayor", 100.00, 'd' },
    { "Paula Bean", 200.00, 'd' },
    { "Gary S."   , 300.00, 'c' },
    { "John Mayor", 400.00, 'c' },
    { 0 } /* sentinel */
};
```

Now simple functions get implemented much more conveniently:

```
double get_balance_struct(const char* name)
{
    double total = 0;
    record_t* tx;
    for (tx = transactions; tx->name; ++tx)
    {
        if (0 == strcmp(tx->name, name)) /* NOTE string comparison! */
        switch(tx->deb_cred)
        {
            case 'c': total += tx->amount; break;
            case 'd': total -= tx->amount; break;
                default:
                    puts("Invalid transaction");
                    exit(255);
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Test:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("Balance: %0.02f\n", get_balance_struct("John Mayor"));
    printf("Balance: %0.02f\n", get_balance_arrays("John Mayor"));
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
Balance: 300.00
Balance: 300.00
```

Comment: Thats probably the proper and most effcient way to do it but im in an entry level programming course and that is too advanced for me plus my prof wouldn't accept it!

Comment: Well, in case it wasn't obvious, you don't **have** to use the struct. I added the same code (`get_balance_arrays`) based on your original arrays example. See them both live at http://ideone.com/QEO0zu